# Laravel input data to multiple tables and validation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

So the problem is, i'm trying to make custom registration using Laravel own scaffolded auth. I have 2 radio buttons above my inputs where user can choose his account type. (User :: Company) First, I made pivot table for users and company and used eloquent relationship.

User model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone',
    'password', 'verified', 'email_token',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

 public function company(){
    $this->belongsToMany('Company', 'user_company');
}
```

Company model:

```
protected $table = 'companies';

protected $fillable = [
    'company', 'reg_nr', 'address',
    'person', 'area_id', 'category_id',
];

public function users(){
    $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_company');
}
```

Register view

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Liitu</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <div class="col-md-offset-5">
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="1" class="user_type"> Eraisik</label>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="2" class="user_type"> Juriidiline isik</label>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <script>
                            $(document).ready(function() {
                                $('.user_type').change(function(){
                                    if( $(this).val() == 1 )
                                    {
                                        $("#company").hide();
                                        $("#reg_input").hide();
                                        $("#address_input").hide();
                                        $("#person_input").hide();
                                        $("#area_input").hide();
                                        $("#category_input").hide();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $("#company").show();
                                        $("#reg_input").show();
                                        $("#address_input").show();
                                        $("#person_input").show();
                                        $("#area_input").show();
                                        $("#category_input").show();
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('first_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="first_name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Eesnimi:</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" value="{{ old('first_name') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('first_name'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('first_name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('last_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="last_name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Perekonnanimi:</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="last_name" type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" value="{{ old('last_name') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('last_name'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('last_name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('contact') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="contact" class="col-md-4 control-label">Tel. nr:</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="contact" type="number" class="form-control" name="contact" value="{{ old('contact') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('contact'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('contact') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('company') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" id="company" style="display: none">
                            <label for="company" class="col-md-4 control-label">Ettevõte:</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="company" type="text" class="form-control" name="company" value="{{ old('company') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('company'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('company') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('category_id') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" id="category_input" style="display: none">
                            <label for="category" class="control-label">Tegevusvaldkond</label>
                            <select name="category_id" id="category" class="form-control{{isset($listing) && $listing->live() ? ' disabled = "disabled' : ''}}">
                                @foreach($categories as $category)
                                    <optgroup label="{{ $category->name }}">
                                        @foreach($category->children as $child)
                                            @if(isset($listing) && $listing->category_id == $child->id || old('category_id') == $child->id)
                                                <option name="category" id="category" value="{{ $child->id }}" selected="selected">{{ $child->name }}</option>
                                            @else
                                                <option name="category" id="category" value="{{ $child->id }}">{{ $child->name }}</option>
                                            @endif
                                        @endforeach
                                    </optgroup>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            @if($errors->has('category_id'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                {{$errors->first('category_id')}}
                            </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('reg_nr') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" id="reg_input" style="display: none">
                            <label for="reg_nr" class="col-md-4 control-label">Reg. nr:</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="reg_nr" type="number" class="form-control" name="reg_nr" value="{{ old('reg_nr') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('reg_nr'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('reg_nr') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('area_id') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" id="area_input" style="display: none">
                            <label for="area" class="control-label">Maakond</label>
                            <select name="area_id" id="area" class="form-control">
                            @foreach($areas  as $country)
                                @foreach($country->children  as $state)
                                    @foreach($state->children  as $city)
                                        @if(
                                            isset($listing) && $listing->area->id == $city->id ||
                                            !isset($listing) && $area->id == $city->id  && !old('area_id')||
                                            old('area_id') == $city->id)
                                            <option name="area" id="area" value="{{ $city->id }}" selected="selected">{{$city->name}}</option>
                                        @else
                                            <option name="area" id="area" value="{{ $city->id }}">{{$city->name}}</option>
                                        @endif
                                    @endforeach
                                @endforeach
                            @endforeach
                            </select>
                            @if($errors->has('area_id'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                {{$errors->first('area_id')}}
                            </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('address') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" id="address_input" style="display: none">
                            <label for="address" class="col-md-4 control-label">Aadress:</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="address" type="text" class="form-control" name="address" value="{{ old('address') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('address'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('address') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('person') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" id="person_input" style="display: none">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Kontakt isik:</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="person" type="text" class="form-control" name="person" value="{{ old('person') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('person'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('person') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Parool</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Kinnita parool</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Liitu
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

RegisterController

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Company;
use DB;
use Mail;
use App\User;
use App\Area;
Use App\Category;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Mail\EmailVerification;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function showRegistrationForm(){

        $areas = Area::all();
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('auth.register', compact('areas', 'categories'));
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {

        return Validator::make($data, [
//            'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
//            'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
//            'company' => 'required|max:255|unique:companies',
//            'reg_nr' => 'required|max:255',
//            'address' => 'required|max:255',
//            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
//            'person' => 'required|max:255',
//            'contact' => 'required',
//            'area' => 'required|max:255',
//            'category' => 'required|max:255',
//            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);

    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(Request $request,array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'contact' => $data['contact'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'email_token' => str_random(10),
        ]);

        $company = Company::create([
            'company' => $data['company'],
            'reg_nr' => $data['reg_nr'],
            'address' => $data['address'],
            'contact' => $data['contact'],
            'area_id' => $data['area'],
            'category_id' => $data['category'],
        ]);

        return $user;
    }
}
```

...now the reason why i removed

validation was just to test, can i submit data to database, but now it doesn't even make POST request to database. Also i tried to use if conditions, but looks like my knowledge about Laravel and PHP is still pretty limited, so i hoping someone can help me out here. Tried to search from google similar problem, but didn't stumble upon anything that can help.

Anyway, basically my final idea about registration is that, when guest goes to register route. He needs to choose between those radio buttons(User::Company) and lets say when guest has chosen just usual User type, he has ability to submit data to users table, and can see only

First_name input
Last_name input
Email input
contact input
password input

and when guest has chosen company type then he can see all inputs, but when company has been created with user, they are stored in two different database tables.

Sorry about bad english, pretty tired over here..
Regards

Comment: Try to put all code in the body of your question. Off-site links expire and many people are rightfully nervous about clicking them.

Comment: Good point..sorry about that. Removed links and added code to code block.

Comment: The problem is that you inserted a lot of code and your error description is basically that the code does not work. I'm sorry, but you need to do some initial debugging and come up with at least a definite error message or a detailed description of unexpected behaviour. If you scroll down the code of the view in the question, then you will see that syntax highlighting goes wrong after a while. I would start there.

Comment: Okay when i removed area and category input from view and fixed few typos, now im getting this error:

`FatalThrowableError in RegisterController.php line 87:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given, called in /Users/user/Desktop/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php on line 33`